# Not able to read all the selected checkbox values from pug in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

The Express MDN tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms/Create_book_form) uses the following code to pull in checkbox values from pug.

From the main code, req.body.genre is supposed to return an array of selected values from a form as below

```
 div.form-group
      label Genre:
      div
        for genre in genres
          div(style='display: inline; padding-right:10px;')
            input.checkbox-input(type='checkbox', name='genre', id=genre._id, value=genre._id, checked=genre.checked )
            label(for=genre._id) #{genre.name}
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

when req.body.genre is referenced in the section of code below in the final middleware function where the new Book model instance is created, it returns only the first value stored as string. Hence the genre field always ends up saving only one value even if multiple checkboxes were ticked in the form.

```
exports.book_create_post = [
    // Convert the genre to an array.
    (req, res, next) => {
        if(!(req.body.genre instanceof Array)){
            if(typeof req.body.genre==='undefined')
            req.body.genre=[];
            else
            req.body.genre=new Array(req.body.genre);
        }
        next();
    },

    // Validate fields.
    body('title', 'Title must not be empty.').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim(),
    body('author', 'Author must not be empty.').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim(),
    body('summary', 'Summary must not be empty.').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim(),
    body('isbn', 'ISBN must not be empty').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim(),

    // Sanitize fields.
    sanitizeBody('*').escape(),
    sanitizeBody('genre.*').escape(),
    // Process request after validation and sanitization.
    (req, res, next) => {


        // Extract the validation errors from a request.
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        // Create a Book object with escaped and trimmed data.
        var book = new Book(
          { title: req.body.title,
            author: req.body.author,
            summary: req.body.summary,
            isbn: req.body.isbn,
            genre: req.body.genre
           });
```

The genre field has been defined to store an array of values

```
var BookSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author', required: true},
    summary: {type: String, required: true},
    isbn: {type: String, required: true},
    genre: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre'}]
  }
);
```

What should i do to be able to get req.body.genre as an array of selected values ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit

This one line of code for express validator created the issue

sanitizeBody('*').escape()

replaced it with

```
sanitizeBody('author').escape(),
sanitizeBody('title').escape(),
sanitizeBody('isbn').escape(),
sanitizeBody('summary').escape(),
sanitizeBody('genre.*').escape(),
```

Now everything works fine. the array is now passed through the req body.